# toggleClass not working

Tags: jquery

I have a series of links that change content of a span element. I'm trying to toggle the classes on them so that users know which section of a profile they are on. It does not seem to be changing the class though.

```
<div class="profilemenu" style="background: #e2ecfd; width: 100%">
   <a style="color: #0b439f;" class="profilemenubutton" id="profile" href="#">Profile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
   <a class="profilemenubutton" id="clanactivity" href="#">Clan Activity</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
   <a class="profilemenubutton" id="recentsessions" href="#">Recent Sessions</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
   <a class="profilemenubutton" id="progress" href="#">Progress</a>
</div>
```

Jquery script.

```
$(\'a#profile\').click (function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "includes/profile.php?username='.$username.'",
    success: function(msg) {
        $(\'span#info\').html(msg);
        $(\'.active\').toggleClass("profilemenubutton");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Why have you got back-slashes in `$(\'a#profile\')` and in all the other selectors?

Comment: it's being echoed by php so I can pass the $username variable in it.

Comment: you do not need to escape the selectors.. just take out the `\\`

Comment: Well, remove the backslashes from all selectors.

Comment: @rlemon, how did you get the `\` (i.e. to get the backslash appear in the StackOverflow markdown) - I can't get it to?

Comment: You don't need to specify the anchor element in the `a#profile` selector. Because IDs are unique on a page, you don't need to specify the element the ID is on.

Comment: @Zabba \`\\\` ;) that took too long to get right.

Comment: I did try that too - wasn't working a second ago :) I must be crazy. testing `\\` testing `\\` testing `\\` :)

Comment: if I take out the \ won't that break what the php script echoes?

Comment: not if you `echo "something 'yadda' '".$username."' hello 'world'";` you don't need `echo "something \'yadda\' '".$username."' hello \'world\'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collective of the information above.

```
echo "$('#profile').click (function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'includes/profile.php?username=".$username."',
    success: function(msg) {
        $('#info').html(msg);
        $('.active').toggleClass'profilemenubutton');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
});";
```

Comment: although looking at your limited markup there is more likely an issue with your selectors

Comment: okay I got it changing the classes correctly, but it doesn't seem to be changing the style.

Comment: Then it's a issue with your CSS. If the class name is truly changed then the DOM element will reflect the CSS rules that are attached to that className

Comment: I noticed it changes the class to class="profilemenubutton active" so would my CSS be .profilemenubutton active {}, then?

Comment: `.profilemenubutton .active {}` or just `.active {}` check to see if you are over writing the rules further down the page. CSS renders in a linear order; Meaning if I write `.red {color:'red';} .red {color:'blue';}` , any textNode with the class `red` will have blue text.

Comment: [CSS2 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) I would suggest you become familiar with both. *For Archaic browser support* ***cough*** *ie* ***cough***

Comment: I got it working it was an issue with jquery ui's stylesheet.